# What is stopping my javascript form running?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing javascript for my intro to computers class. The assignment is to create a webpage with a calculator that converts a decimal number into binary, into its ones complement, and into its twos complement. I've got the binary function working just fine...but after coding what I felt would work for the ones complement function...everything stopped working. Any tip in the right direction would be so helpful! Here's my code:

```
function decimalToBinary() {
  var decimal;
  var decimalInput = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;
  decimal = Number(decimalInput);
  var binary = decimal.toString(2);
  while (binary.length < 8) {
    binary = "0" + binary;
  }

  //var oneComp = onesComplement(binary);
  var prettyString = binary.substring(0, 4) + " " + binary.substring(4);
  prettyString = decimal.toString() + " decimal is " + prettyString;
  prettyString = prettyString + " binary.";
  document.getElementById("answerString").innerHTML = prettyString;
  var prettyString2 = oneComp.substring(0, 4) + " " + oneComp.substring(4);
  prettyString2 = oneComp.toString() + " one's complement is " + prettyString2;
  document.getElementById("answerString2").innerHTML = prettyString2;
}

function onesComplement(binaryNumberString) {
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if binaryNumberString.substring(i, 1) == 0 {
      binaryNumberString.substring(i, 1) = 1;
    } else {
      binaryNumberString.substring(i, 1) = 0;
    }
    return binaryNumberString;
  }
}
```

Also, the html of my page is written as such to pick up the input:

```
<body>
    <input type = "text" id="numberInput" />
    <button onClick = "decimalToBinary()">Convert</button>
    <p id="answerString">The answer will be here</p>
    <p id="answerString2">Second Answer</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the console in your browser? Does it show any javascript errors?

Comment: String primitive values are immutable; you can't set a substring. Your function should build a *new* string. Also you can get the character at a particular index more simply with `.charAt(i)`. Also also, declare `i` with `var`!!

Comment: You clearly have a syntax error that should be mentioned by the console of your browser.

Comment: I opened the console, and I have this error listed: binaryscript.html:26 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Let's see what I can find

Comment: @MitchMiller did you find it?  If not what is shown for you in line `26`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your script fixed:

```
<body>
    <script>
        function decimalToBinary() {
            var decimal;
            var decimalInput = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;
            decimal = Number(decimalInput);
            var binary = decimal.toString(2);
            while (binary.length < 8) {
                binary = "0" + binary;
            }

            var oneComp = onesComplement(binary);
            var prettyString = binary.substring(0, 4) + " " + binary.substring(4);
            prettyString = decimal.toString() + " decimal is " + prettyString;
            prettyString = prettyString + " binary.";
            document.getElementById("answerString").innerHTML = prettyString;
            var prettyString2 = oneComp.substring(0, 4) + " " + oneComp.substring(4);
            prettyString2 = oneComp.toString() + " one's complement is " + prettyString2;
            document.getElementById("answerString2").innerHTML = prettyString2;
        }

        function onesComplement(binaryNumberString) {
            var binNum = '';
            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

                if (binaryNumberString.substring(i, 1) == 0) {
                    binNum = binNum + '1';
                } else {
                    binNum = binNum + '0';
                }
                return binNum;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="numberInput" />
    <button onClick="decimalToBinary()">Convert</button>
    <p id="answerString">The answer will be here</p>
    <p id="answerString2">Second Answer</p>
</body>
```

You had a few errors, a var commented out, missing parenthesis, and you were trying to set a value to a function call.  Review the code and compare you'll see your issues.

I'm not saying this is the best way to accomplish your goals, I simply fixed the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `onesComplement` you are missing the brackets in the if statement.

`if (binaryNumberString.substring(i, 1) == 0) {`

Comment: He was missing parenthesis "(" and ")", not brackets "[" or "]"   :)